# Unable to retrieve width of dynamically loaded label with autosize as true

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I a bit stuck here. I am trying to dynamically add panel with two labels in it.

The first label must be auto sized and the second label should be positioned to the left of the first one which has a fixed max width and its also auto sized. My code is a follows

```
        pnlSearchResults.SuspendLayout(); 

        Panel pnlRow = new Panel
        {
            AutoSize = true,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Padding = new Padding(0),
            Margin = new Padding(0),
            Top = 0,
            Left = 0,
            Width = pnlSearchResults.Width - 30,
            MaximumSize = new Size(pnlSearchResults.Width - 30, 0)
        };

        Label lblKey = new Label
        {
            Name = string.Format("lblKey{0}", 1),
            Text = "My label goes here",
            AutoSize = true,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Padding = new Padding(0),
            Margin = new Padding(0),
            Top = 0,
            Left = 0,
        };

        pnlRow.Controls.Add(lblKey);

        Label lblValue = new Label
        {
            Name = string.Format("lblValue{0}", 1),
            Text = "And my long text goes here... and it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and ...",
            AutoSize = true,
            Height = 27,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Padding = new Padding(0),
            Margin = new Padding(0),
            Top = 0,
            MaximumSize = new Size(pnlRow.Width - lblKey.Width - 10, 0),
            Left = lblKey.PreferredWidth
        };
        pnlRow.Controls.Add(lblValue);
        pnlSearchResults.Controls.Add(pnlRow);
        pnlSearchResults.ResumeLayout();
        pnlSearchResults.PerformLayout();
```

I read that calling suspend, resume or perform methods increases performance. And this is what im getting.

[image]

As you can see the second label is not getting properly aligned with the first label. Its working fine if i set autosize = false for first label, but I want my first label to be auto sized.

I am not sure what I am missing here, please guide me in the proper way.

Comment: looks like your first lable **can't** be autosized that way (with `AutoSize` = true). You have to disable `AutoSize` and implement your own kind of autosizing. It requires wrapping here. You should take some look at `Dock` with `DockStyle.Left`. There is no need to size the Bounds of your first label to match the exact size of the Text if you don't use any Border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because the label has not yet been drawn and therefore adjusted itself to the correct size. If you want this to work you cannot suspend and resume layouts, you cannot place the controls before the form is shown and you will probably need to call a Refresh in between placing the labels to allow the 1st one to autosize correctly.